# Spring webservice client xml parameter

Tags: xml, web-services, spring, parameter-passing

I am tasked to create a simple tool, invoking a specific, SOAP-based web service.

I am new to Java Spring Framework and Web services in general. I have been reading up on both for a while now.

So far, I am able to invoke a method, which does not have parameters and get back the result, but I hav trouble adding parameters to the request.

Code so far:

```
String msg = "<methodname xmlns=\"http://www.namespace.com/\">" +
                        "<param1>TEST</param1>"+
                        "<param2>TEST</param2>"+
                 "</methodname>";
    ApplicationContext appCon = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("appCon.xml");
    BeeSmartSpringConnector bee = (BeeSmartSpringConnector) appCon.getBean("BeeSmartConnector");
    bee.setDefaultUri("http://127.0.0.1:85/WebServices/TestBean?wsdl");
    bee.simpleSendAndReceive(msg);
```

As a result, the webservice returns the message:

```
Required parameter not found! --&gt; Parameters : param1="null", param2="null"
```

According to the WSDL-file those two parameters are exactly what the method needs.

Can you please tell what I did wrong? Maybe wrong formatting of request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting msg as...

```
String msg = "<ns:methodname xmlns:ns=\"http://www.namespace.com/\">" +
                        "<param1>TEST</param1>"+
                        "<param2>TEST</param2>"+
                 "</ns:methodname>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but even after trying both ns and ns2 I got the same result

Comment: then I would suggest you to check the namespaces and parameters... Also does webservice server works properly?

Comment: The server is remote and is not part of our company. I assume it works properly. The response from the webservice comes via ns2

Comment: Update: using <ns2:param1>TEST</ns2:param1> or param2 respectivly did not change anything. The peculiar thing is, that it works for remote methods, that are parameterless. There I get a decent response containing the desired information.